# Who established the tradition of using $X^{\prime}$ instead of $X^{T}$ to denote the matrix transpose?

Tags: matrices, notation, math-history, transpose

From being away from mathematicians for a while and spending most of my time with econometricians and statisticians, one thing I've noticed is that econometricians and statisticians like to use $\prime$ to denote the matrix transpose, e.g., $X^{\prime}$.

However, when you show this notation to a mathematician, they'd think that you mean a matrix distinct from $X$; i.e., $X$ and $X^{\prime}$ are just two distinct matrices with no explicit relation. Hence when I'm on MSE, I always try to use $X^{T}$ instead.

My guess is that the $X^{T}$ notation has been around longer than $X^{\prime}$. Who was the first to use $X^{\prime}$ to denote the matrix transpose?

Comment: Perhaps this has something to do with consistency with the notation used in mathematical softwares. Though it is probably not the specific answer to the question.

Comment: If you show that notation to a (sensible) mathematician, she would ask you what the prime means, not assume that the the matrices are unrelated.

Comment: In any case, I doubt your question («who was the first to use that notation for the transpose?») has any chance whatsoever of being answered with anything more than a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *A History of Mathematical Notations* (vol. 2) by Florian Cajori (1929) on [p. 103](https://archive.org/stream/b29980343_0002#page/102/mode/2up), the use of $A^{\prime}$ to denote the "conjugate" of a matrix $A$ (what we now usually call the "transpose") is credited to

> C.E. Cullis, *Matrices and Determinoids* (Cambridge), Vol. I (1913)

This notation is defined in [p. 5 of that text](https://books.google.com/books?id=LqL5rrXcY7MC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false). From kimchi lover's answer, it appears that $A^{\prime}$ predates $A^{T}$.

Comment: This is great! Well done.

Answer (score 7):

I did a spot check on some books:

**Prime**
Birkhoff and MacLane, *Survey of Modern Algebra* (1953), Faddeeva, *Computational Methods of Linear Algebra* (trans 1959), and P. Halmos, *Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces* (1958) all use $A'$ for the transpose of $A$.  As do Wedderburn *Lectures on Matrices* (1934) and Turnbull and Aitken *Theory of Canonical Matrices* (1932).

**T**
But Macduffee *Vectors and Matrices* (1942) and Gantmacher *Matrix Theory* (1953, trans 1959) both use  $A^T$.  Macduffee's 1933 *The Theory of Matrices* has some relevant info: on page 5, when the term *transpose* and his symbol $A^T$ first appear, he gives a footnote reading

> Or conjugate. Many different notations for the transpose have been used, as $A'$, $\bar A$, $\breve{A}$, $A^*$, $A_1$, ${}_tA$. The present notation is in keeping with a systematic notation which, it is hoped, may find favor.

This makes me think Macduffee introduced the $A^T$ notation, and that the $A'$ notation predates it.

**Neither**
The local library has Bocher, *Introduction to Higher Algebra* (1907) which does not have a special symbol for transpose.

Comment: It's worth noting that http://jeff560.tripod.com/matrices.html also cites Macduffee for $A^T$ and Wedderburn for $A^{\prime}$.

Comment: @Clarinetist Good!  The site you cite is awesome!  I can believe $A^T$ was invented by Macduffee, but surely $A'$ predates Wedderburn.

Comment: I posted an answer. I think it's the best I'll be able to find.